# How to remove words from an array in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

In a string, how to check and remove words which exist in a given array?

```
$string = "This is a test string for testing the process";

$array = array('test', 'something', ....);
```

In the given example, I want to remove "test" but not "testing". I wishes to use a simple method like `str_replace`

```
$string = str_replace($array, "", $string);
```

since `str_replace` accepts an array as input, but the problem is that it does not differentiate between a word and substring in a word.

Another option is to `explore` the string with space to check the words in each element, but I hope to find a simpler method.

Comment: You can use `preg_replace()` with word boundaries, e.g. `echo preg_replace("/\b(" . implode("|", $array) . ")\b/", "", $string);`